# Returning a string from a Python function

Tags: python, string, return

```
def God():
    set_path()

    find_files(path)

def set_path():
    '''Sets file path to inputted directory'''

    # Should path default to a certain directory if path is invalid?
    # (it does here)
    #path = Path(input("Enter path\n"))
    path = Path(input("Specify a directory:\n")
    print("Path set to", path.cwd())
    return path



def find_files(path):
    '''Stores files in current dir and all subdirs to a list'''

    myFiles = []
    for element in path.iterdir():
        if element.is_dir() == True:
            find_files(element)
        else:
            myFiles.append(element)
    print(myFiles)
    return myFiles
```

*** The God function combines the two functions and should return a list of all the files in the directory and subdirectory of the set path, however I keep receiving this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    God()
  File "C:/Users/Project1.py", line 8, in God
    return path
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

Any ideas on how to return the string for later use in the God function and all later functions as well?

Comment: Does this even compile? You're missing parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't that `set_path` isn't returning the path — it *is* returning it — but that its caller is discarding the return-value.

To fix this, change this line:

```
    set_path()
```

to this:

```
    path = set_path()
```